# Can not understand the session object behavior

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, session-management

I am confused on the documentation of the [javax.servlet.http.HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.1/api/javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.html).
It says:

> Sessions are used to maintain state and user identity across multiple
>   page requests. A session can be maintained either by using cookies or
>   by URL rewriting.

Now both cookies and URL rewriting are handled by application code in server (i.e. our code).

Then it says relating to when a session is considered as `new`:

> The server considers a session to be new until it has been joined by
>   the client.   Until the client joins the session, the isNew method
>   returns true.A value of true can indicate one of these three cases:
>       1. the client does not yet know about the session
>       2. the session has not yet begun
>       3. the client chooses not to join the session. This case will occur if the client supports only cookies and chooses to reject any cookies
>   sent by the server. If the server supports URL rewriting, this case
>   will not commonly occur.

I am not clear on when it is considered/meant that the `client has joined the session`.

I mean if I don't use cookies from my web application (or URL rewriting) and I have the following:

1. POST from IP A to server
2. 200 OK from server to A
3. POST from IP A to server

In step 3 will the `session.isNew()` return true or false? It is not clear to me from the doc.
Will it return false (i.e. the session is not new) and I will have to call `session.invalidate()` in order to create a new session?
The reason this confuses me more is because I am debugging a piece of code where the client is an HTTP application but not a web brower and I see that in step 3 the `session.isNew()` does not return `true` although there is no cookies or url rewriting in the server code.
So I can not figure out what is going out under the hood.
Any info that could help understand this?

Comment: You seem to be confused about cookies: the servlet container will add the session cookie for you in the response, and read it for you from the request. You don't need to do anything. If the client browser doesn't accept cookies, URL rewriting will automatically be used, and will work provided that you always encode your URLs (with encodeURL, encodeRedirectURL, or the appropriate JSP tags)

Comment: @JB Nizet:I thought HTTP is stateless.So it's up to the programmer to maintain sessions.So you are telling me that there is a session by container anyway?

Comment: When you ask the container to create a session (using request.getSession() or request.getSession(true)), the container adds a session cookie to the next response sent to the client, and appends the session ID to the encoded URLs). When it receives the cookie from the next request (or the session ID at the end of the URL), it can associate the request to the previously created session. You don't have to do anything except encoding URLs if your clients don't accept cookies. Session tracking and timeout is done by the container.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise that `request.getSession()` created the `session`. Very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice example of [Session Tracking](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Servlets11.html#wp64784)

`Client has joined the session` means that client made subsequent request and included session id, which can be recognized by your webserver. If cookies are enabled - `jsessionid` will be passed with cookies, otherwise - it should be include in the URL itself - like this `http://localhost:8080/bookstore1/cashier;jsessionid=c0o7fszeb1`.

In JSP `c:url` from Core Tag Library will handle URL rewriting for you.

In case of B2B communication you have to obtain session id by yourself and include it in subsequent requests manually.

**Example:**

1. POST from IP A to server
2. 200 OK from server to A
3. A obtains `session id` from the response
4. POST from IP A to server and includes obtained `session id`

**UPDATE:**

Consider reading a great article - ["Web Based Session Management: Best practices in managing HTTP-based client sessions."](http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/WebBasedSessionManagement.html)  It's a general overview of how HTTP sessions can be emulated and is not tied to Java.

Comment: Isn't `jsessionid` java specific?

Comment: Yes, it's java specific. JavaEE compliant server has to use this name, though some servers allow to configure this name.

Comment: But the client I am using is not in Java

Comment: As your session is being tracked by a Java web server your non-java client has to extract jsessionid from response and use it in subsequent requests in order to help  Java web server to track the session.

Comment: @ Ivan:I did not write the client and I don't have access to its code. I am just trying to understand what is going on.So you are saying that the non-java client code extracts the `jsessionid` to use it in later requests, that is why this works?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but probably yes - it extracts the `jsessionid`.

Comment: @user384706: read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie. The browser doesn't care about cookie names. You tell him "here's a cookie for my web app", and the browser sends this cookie with every request sent to this web app. The name doesn't matter. JEE chose to standardize on jsessionid, just as PHP chose to use PHPSESSID.